# Array Index merge of the same array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, merge

I have faced a problem. I have an array looks like this

```
print_r($log_ret_val);
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [TestingLogDevice] => Array ( [Siteid] => Mirpur_CO ) ) 
                       [1] => Array ( [TestingLogDevice] => Array ( [Siteid] => Mirpur_CO ) ) 
      ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [TestingLogDevice] => Array ( [Tempin] => 29 ) ) 
                       [1] => Array ( [TestingLogDevice] => Array ( [Tempin] => 29 ) ) 
      ) 
        [2] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [TestingLogDevice] => Array ( [Date_time] => 18.11.2017 11:03:33 ) ) 
                       [1] => Array ( [TestingLogDevice] => Array ( [Date_time] => 18.11.2017 11:00:31 ) ) 
     ) 
)
```

And this is what I write for that value

```
$log_val        = array();
foreach ($log_ret_val as $key => $valuee) {
    foreach ($valuee as $key => $val) {
        array_push($log_val,$val);
    }
}
print_r($log_val);

Array ( [0] => Array ( [TestingLogDevice] => Array ( [Siteid] => Mirpur_CO ) ) 
        [1] => Array ( [TestingLogDevice] => Array ( [Siteid] => Mirpur_CO ) ) 
        [2] => Array ( [TestingLogDevice] => Array ( [Tempin] => 29 ) )                   
        [3] => Array ( [TestingLogDevice] => Array ( [Tempin] => 28 ) ) 
        [4] => Array ( [TestingLogDevice] => Array ( [Date_time] => 18.11.2017 11:24:45 ) ) 
        [5] => Array ( [TestingLogDevice] => Array ( [Date_time] => 18.11.2017 11:21:43 ) ) 
)
```

But my desired output looks like this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [TestingLogDevice] => Array ( [Siteid] => Mirpur_CO [Tempin] => 29 [Date_time] => 18.11.2017 11:24:45 ) ) 
        [1] => Array ( [TestingLogDevice] => Array ( [Siteid] => Mirpur_CO [Tempin] => 28 [Date_time] => 18.11.2017 11:21:43 ) ) 
)
```

So what can I do meet up my desired output. For your kind suggestion or help please

Comment: Can you give sample for `$log_ret_val` array? Thanks

Comment: difficult as I don't see how you are going to match up the extra fields....maybe do a `for loop` and skip evens?

Comment: @Erwin add $log_ret_val value

Comment: could you post your `raw array ` @A.ANoman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through `$log_ret_val` extract it key and use `array_merge_recursive` to create new array

```
$log_ret_val = Array ( "0" => Array ( "0" => Array ( "TestingLogDevice" => Array ( "Siteid" => "Mirpur_CO" ) ) ,
                       "1" => Array ( "TestingLogDevice" => Array ( "Siteid" => "Mirpur_CO" ) ) ,
  ) ,
        "1" => Array ( "0" => Array ( "TestingLogDevice" => Array ( "Tempin" => 29 ) ) ,
                      "1" => Array ( "TestingLogDevice" => Array ( "Tempin" => 29 ) ) ,
  ) ,
        "2" => Array ( "0" => Array ( "TestingLogDevice" => Array ( "Date_time" => "18.11.2017 11:03:33" ) ) ,
                       "1" => Array ( "TestingLogDevice" => Array ( "Date_time" => "18.11.2017 11:00:31" ) ) 
  )
  ); 
$log_val = array();
foreach ($log_ret_val as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        if(isset($log_val[$key1]))
            $log_val[$key1] = array_merge_recursive($log_val[$key1],$value1);
        else
            $log_val[$key1] = array_merge_recursive($value1);
    }
}
print_r($log_val);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/NloQg)